# Create a combobox/drop-down with dynamic list based on a cell entry

Tags: excel, vba

I have to manage a few cars and I need to create a combobox list with the available cars to choose.

But we have some restrictions and each car are not available in a certain day of the week. (For example, car A, and B are not available Mondays and C and D are not available Fridays).

I already created a table with each car it's respective unavailable weekday and I already have a variable that shows what weekday is today, so I can verify them.

Bottom line: I need it to check each car and if *today* is different than the car's index, add it to the combobox list.

I made it work by manually checking each row with If. But I add another car to the list, I have to add it again on the code. Id like it to check every line

Comment: You could probably make a subroutine out of it and give it an argument. Hard to get any more detailed as you did not include your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with drop-down lists without using VBA. You might be able to adapt it to your needs.

This method has 3 parts:

1. The list of cars and their day off
2. The dynamically generated list
3. The drop-down (Daily Actions)

[image: Illustration of cars available list for Friday]

In this example, the Car List table has cars (Col D) and days off (Col E). Per your scenario, cars A and B are off on Mondays, while C and D are off on Fridays (a new car E is off on Wednesdays). Column F contains a formula, assigning a number to those cars that are available on the selected day. In cell F5: `=IF(E5 = $B$4, "", MAX($F$4:F4) + 1)` says if the car is not available, leave it blank, otherwise assign it 1 more than the largest number already assigned. Copy the formula down the column. Those numbers will be matched to the Sequence in the next section.

The Dynamic List Contents section creates the actual list of cars for the drop-down box. Col H (Sequence) is just sequential numbers. Column I (Index) is a formula that determines the position in the Car List of each available car. In cell I5: `=IFNA(MATCH(H5, $F$5:$F$9, 0), "")` That matches the 1st, 2nd, etc. available car in the car list. (Cars A, B, and E are available on Fridays; they are 1st, 2nd, and 5th in the Car List.) The resulting dynamic list is in Col J. In cell J5: `IFERROR(INDEX($D$5:$D$9, I5), "")` That simply matches the car name to the Index. Again, copy the formulas down the columns. The list in Col J is used as the source for the Data Validation for the Select Car cell (B6) for a drop-down box.

Adding another car requires extending both the Car List table and the Dynamic List Contents another row and copying the formulas to the new rows. The references to the Car List in the Dynamic List Contents must also be updated to include the new row.

I'd recommend keeping the Car List and the Dynamic List Contents sections from the daily actions, because you interact with them only for maintenance, when you have to add or delete a car, or change a day off.

To use, in the Daily Actions section, enter the day, then click the Select Car list. It will contain those cars listed in Col J, as in the screen shot for Friday. You can eliminate those blank entries at the end of the list by using a dynamic range name for the list source, but that's beyond the scope of this example. Search SO for "Excel dynamic range name" or something similar if you need help with that.

If this helps you, please don't forget to mark it accepted. Thanks!